# Figuring out tables for company orders

Tags: database-design

I am working on restructuring the 'database' my company uses, and have hit a bit of a wall on the design of a specific area for the data tables.

I need to setup the data model such that we can create Purchase Orders, store the data for them and track multiple data points on these orders.  These data points include; parts ordered, quantity of each part ordered, price of each part (which can change between quote and the submitted order), the supplier, our contact for the supplier, the associated job, when the order was placed, when the parts were received, and whether or not any parts are on backorder.

As you can see it's a lot of data to spread through some tables.  My first instinct was to come up with the following table layout:

```
Table: purchase_order
    order_id     INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    order_number VARCHAR(20)
    job_id       INT
    supplier_id  INT
    contact_id   INT
    notes        VARCHAR(MAX) 
    PK = order_id

Table: order_status
    status_id          INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    status_description VARCHAR(50)
    PK = order_id

Table order_part
    order_id     INT
    part_id      INT
    status_id    INT
    ordered      INT
    received     INT
    log_date     DATE
    user_list_id INT
    notes        VARCHAR(MAX)
    PK = order_id, part_id, status_id

Table: order_part_price
    log_id        INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    order_id      INT
    part_id       INT
    part_price_id INT
    conversion_id INT
    log_date      DATE
    PK = log_id
```

With this setup, I can do the things I mentioned above, though I can definitely see some flaws with it.  One of the things I am concerned with at the moment is with concerns to tracking parts ordered and parts received.  The way it is set up above, when parts are received, the `order_parts` table would get a new entry, with the `received` column containing how many parts have been received.  Outside of that and the change in the status from `Ordered` to `Received` or `Backordered` that rest of the row's data would be the exact same as the data for the initial entry when the order was made.  As such, I've thought up the following revised table setup:

```
Table: purchase_order
    order_id    INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    order_num   VARCHAR(20)
    job_id      INT
    supplier_id INT
    contact_id  INT
    status_id   INT
    PK = order_id

Table: order_part
    order_id     INT
    part_id      INT
    quantity     INT
    log_date     DATE
    user_list_id INT
    PK = order_id, part_id

Table: shipment
    order_id     INT
    part_id      INT
    received     INT
    log_date     DATE
    user_list_id INT
    PK = order_id, part_id
```

Essentially I am splitting the old `order_part` table into two separate tables, one that deals with ordering parts, and one that deals with receiving parts.  I am also moving the status identifier to the `purchase_order` table since the status is part of the whole order, even if individual parts are the ones being backordered.

Now my question is, does this change make sense?  What are some other obvious flaws in my original design that I am missing?  Does my new design give me some problems I didn't have before?

This is the first large scale Database project I have worked on so I am trying to make it as best as I can possibly manage.  Thanks for your time.